# Error when running trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

Created the following trigger to move asset tags to their correct field.

Getting an error though.   Not a database guy.

```
CREATE TRIGGER HARRISOP.ASSET_TAG INSTEAD OF  INSERT  ON DB2ADMIN.SNMPSYS FOR EACH                                                                                STATEMENT MODE DB2SQL 
   SELECT * 
   FROM DB2ADMIN.SNMPSYS AS SNMPSYS
   WHERE SNMPSYS.SYSCONTACT_X = ' A330637'
   INSERT INTO DB2ADMIN.CITEMPLATE (ASSETTAG_X)
   VALUES (DEFAULT)
```

New COde as per User help.  Still no go.

```
CONNECT TO CMDB;
CREATE TRIGGER DB2ADMIN.ASSET_TAG NO CASCADE BEFORE  INSERT  ON DB2ADMIN.SNMPSYS  FOR EACH ROW  MODE DB2SQL 
REFERENCING 
    NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW 
MODE DB2SQL
SET N.ASSETTAG_X = SUBSTR(
  N.SYSCONTACT_X, 
  1, 
  LOCATE(',', N.SYSCONTACT_X) - 1
);
CONNECT RESET;
```

Comment: I really just want to grab everything up to the , in  a field. Tivoli is grabbing the SNMP info and putting it in the location field.  
EX.       A12345567, Ottawa Ontario.  We have a ton of different looking assets so I need to just move all the characters up to the , out to another field.  Again no a DB guy so any help would be appreciated.  Using DB2 database.

Comment: The syntax for both the trigger itself and for the insert statement is incorrect. I don't see any commas or a location field in your SQL either. Please explain in human terms what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have a snmp field that is called syscontact_x.   I need to move some  of the data out and into the correct field call assettag_x. The asset tag and the current location text is like this  Example.  A12345567, Ottawa Ontario.   I need to move the A1234567 to the correct field.  I want to create a trigger that fires when an insert or update happends on that field and moves the data.  I am using DB2 and using its built in SQL assist to create the trigger and that is what it came up with. I can't find a more manual way to do it.  Hope that answers your questions.  Thanks

Comment: Looks like I got it part way done.. Just need help on the actual move of the data selected.  CONNECT TO CMDB;
CREATE TRIGGER DB2ADMIN.ASSET_TAG NO CASCADE BEFORE  INSERT  ON DB2ADMIN.SNMPSYS  FOR EACH ROW  MODE DB2SQL 
SELECT SNMPSYS.SYSCONTACT_X
   FROM DB2ADMIN.SNMPSYS AS SNMPSYS
   WHERE SNMPSYS.SYSCONTACT_X LIKE '%,'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, the trigger should look something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER HARRISOP.ASSET_TAG 
BEFORE INSERT   
ON DB2ADMIN.SNMPSYS 
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW 
SET N.ASSETTAG_X = SUBSTR(
  N.SYSCONTACT_X, 
  1, 
  LOCATE(',', N.SYSCONTACT_X) - 1
)
```

You should read more about triggers in the manual: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0020225.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer..Get this.[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "FOR EACH 
ROW  MODE DB2SQL  REFERENCING NEW" was found following "ON 
DB2ADMIN.SNMPSYS".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".  
LINE NUMBER=2.  SQLSTATE=42601.  I have read so much on triggers I don't know what is what anymore..This should be so simple to move everything before the  , to assettag_x field.

Comment: I don't see any `MODE DB2SQL` in the code I provided. Pay attention to the sequence of keywords -- while you can put on your socks before your pants, computers ain't like that.

Comment: Yeah sorry ignore that ...Was using SQL helper and it put it in.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you able to copy and paste the code exactly as I provided, or do you insist on introducing your own syntax errors into it? Compare what you run and what I have shown.

Comment: I have tried coping and pasting and still the same error as above.The Connect to CMDB is put in automatically by DB2 and the harrisop was incorrect by me it should be as shown above db2admin... I create the trigger by right clicking on the field and choosing create trigger it puts that in on its own. Hopefully I haven't completely confused you.  Very frusterated that this isn't working and it needs to be by monday. Thank you

Comment: Well, as you may have noticed, whatever you are _right-clicking_ introduces duplicate `for each row` and `mode db2sql` clauses. You'll have to figure out the way to create the trigger verbatim somehow. Good luck.